# Why does the Count-Min Sketch require pairwise independent hash functions?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, randomized-algorithms, hash

The [Count-Min Sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count-Min_sketch) is an awesome data structure for estimating the frequencies of different elements in a data stream.  Intuitively, it works by picking a variety of hash functions, hashing each element with those hash functions, and incrementing the frequencies of various slots in various tables.  To estimate the frequency of an element, the Count-Min sketch applies the hash functions to those elements and takes the minimum value out of all the slots that are hashed to.

The [original paper on the Count-Min Sketch](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/CS222/countmin.pdf) mentions that the data structure requires pairwise independent hash functions in order to get the necessary guarantees on its expected performance.  However, looking over the structure, I don't see why pairwise independence is necessary.  Intuitively, I would think that all that would be required would be that the hash function be [a universal hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing), since universal hash functions are hash functions with low probabilities of collisions.  The analysis of the collision probabilities in the Count-Min Sketch looks remarkably similar to the analysis of collision probabilities in a chained hash table (which only requires a family of universal hash functions, not pairwise independent hash functions), and I can't spot the difference in the analyses.

Why is it necessary for the hash functions in the Count-Min Sketch to be pairwise independent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right: universal hashing suffices. Pairwise independence, while stronger, is the usual method to construct a universal hash family. Also pairwise independence is contrasted in the paper with the 4-wise independence required by previous methods, such as the AMS sketch.

Comment: Can you expand on why this is sufficient? It seems to me that in the last line of the proof on page 7, they use the fact that $P[(\forall j \in [1,d]). x_j > a] = (P[x_j > a])^d$, which seems to rely on the $d$ hash functions having independent probabilities of collision. Is this property implied by universal hashing?

Comment: @usul universality is used in the first equation on p 7 (this equation is in fact the definition of universality). what you are saying is true not because of any property of the hash family used, it is simply a consequence of the fact that each of the $d$ hash functions are chosen independently from each other!

Comment: and universality is sufficient because the only property of the hash family ever used is the equation on top of p.7 and this is the defining property of a universal hash family

Comment: I think this comes down to an omission in the paper: Do we choose a *set* of $d$ independent hash functions uniformly at random, or do we select each hash function from the family independently and uniformly at random (with replacement)? It doesn't quite specify. I assumed the former, but if we assume the latter, then I agree the statement follows trivially.

Comment: The text by [Mitzenmacher and Upfal](http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Computing-Randomized-Algorithms-Probabilistic/dp/0521835402), in describing a Count-Min filter (pgs 328-331) use only universal hash functions, not pairwise independence, and they choose their hash functions independently and uniformly at random. So your answer is certainly correct.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  This has really been bugging me, and it's good to hear that I'm not missing something.  Probability isn't my strong suit.

Comment: @usul i am not sure i get your question, but the description in the paper is on p.6, at the top. you fix a family of universal hash functions, and uniformly and independently pick $d$ functions from the family, with replacement.

Comment: @Sasho, the word "independently" in your statement is not present in the paper linked above. It says "$d$ hash functions are chosen uniformly at random from a pairwise-independent family."

Comment: @usul you are right. to me this always seemed like the obvious interpretation of what they say, esp. given the analysis. it's an occam's razor thing: why would you sample hash functions without replacement, i've never seen that done in an algorithm. but fair point, nonetheless.